# Shear coordinates, lambda lengths, cluster variables

Tags: riemann-surfaces, teichmuller-theory, cluster-algebras

I am trying to understand the relations among Shear coordinates, lambda lengths, cluster variables, in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.5569.pdf). Is the following correct?

1. Lambda lengths = cluster A-variables
2. Shear coordinates = cluster X-variables

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes.  Note that what some people call (A,X), others would call (X,Y).